# Jinja2 loop does not execute

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I'm sending a dictionary with three lists:

```
attendance = {
    'total': ['1', ' 5', ' 8', ' 12', ' 15', ' 19', ' 22', ' 26'],
    'sick-note': ['5'],
    'unattended': ['1']
}
```

I want to display each value in the total list as a separate item. It does not work, the value 1 is always displayed. Why isn't the loop executing the increment?

```
<ul>
    {% set count = 0 %}
    {% for i in attendance.total %}
        <li>{{ attendance.total[count] }}</li>
        {% set count = count + 1 %}
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you do loops in Python or in Jinja. You should use the loop variable. You don't need `count` at all.

```
<ul>
     {% for i in attendance['total'] %}
     <li>{{ i }}</li>
     {% endfor %}
 </ul>
```